# Is there a free version for HangFire with Redis?

Tags: redis, hangfire

Is there a way to use HangFire free version with Redis database?

Answer (score 10):

I tried [Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange](https://github.com/marcoCasamento/Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange) package some time ago with free version 1.7.3 of Hangfire. And it seemed to work quite well at that time.

So I would say that there is a way.